# Apache Flink 1.16 - RestartStrategies is not working

Tags: apache-flink

I have use case to retry logic if any exception happening . I have added the checkpoint and RestartStrategies, but Flink is not restarting the job if any exception. Is any other property need to add. Can you please suggest any examples for this.

```
  streamExecutionEnvironment.enableCheckpointing(2000);
      //  streamExecutionEnvironment.setParallelism(2);

        // advanced options:

        // set mode to exactly-once (this is the default)
        streamExecutionEnvironment.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointingMode(CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE);

        // checkpoints have to complete within one minute, or are discarded
        streamExecutionEnvironment.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointTimeout(60000);

        // allow only one checkpoint to be in progress at the same time
        streamExecutionEnvironment.getCheckpointConfig().setMaxConcurrentCheckpoints(1);

        streamExecutionEnvironment.setRestartStrategy(RestartStrategies.fixedDelayRestart(
                3, // number of restart attempts
                Time.of(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // delay
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, checkpoints are stored on the job manager's heap, which is a rather fragile setup (you'll lose the checkpoints if the JM fails or is restarted). In order to use `FileSystemCheckpointStorage`, you should configure the checkpoint directory, either in `flink-conf.yaml`

```yaml
state.checkpoints.dir: file:///checkpoint-dir/
```

or in your code

```java
env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointStorage("file:///checkpoint-dir");
```

It could also be the case that the job is failing before the first checkpoint completes.

There also has to be something still running that can restart the job, such as a job manager, or a kubernetes operator. If you are running in a mini-cluster, this won't work.

Comment: I have added the checkpoint storage still the same issue. I am explicitly creating a exception in the code to check the retry . Is that correct approach. My understanding of the retry is , If any exception in the job , it will retry based on the value which we configured. So After the exception its not retrying . Anything else I missed.

Comment: Are you sure that the first checkpoint completes before the exception occurs?

Comment: Also, how are you running the job? Is this a remote cluster with a separate Job Manager, or is everything running in a single JVM (in a "mini-cluster")?

Comment: We have Flink integrated with spring boot application . So am running in my local and testing the same . Since other DAG are working fine

Comment: See the last paragraph I added to my answer above. It sounds like you may not be running Flink in a way that can support failure recovery.

Comment: If you want to experiment with and understand failure recovery, I suggest working through the operations playground: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/try-flink/flink-operations-playground/#observing-failure--recovery You could modify the job in that playground, and add a restart strategy to it.

Comment: HI, I have followed the same , Checkpoints are created and its recreating the task if any failed. But How Do I confirm , Retry is working , For Ex, There is a API outage inside the task, So its failed, I wanted to retry the same task with the same payload. Is it possible ?. IF so Ho do I confirm its retrying with number of attempt which I mentioned in the config.

Comment: You could study the tests in https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-tests/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/test/recovery for inspiration.